# How to use Sum on array of strings - LINQ?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, parsing, sum

How to sum array of strings with LINQ Sum method?

I have string which looks like: `"1,2,4,8,16"`

I have tried:

```
string myString = "1,2,4,8,16";
int number = myString.Split(',').Sum((x,y)=> y += int.Parse(x));
```

But it says that cannot `Parse` source type `int` to type ?.

I do not want to use a `foreach` loop to sum this numbers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're mis-calling `Sum()`.

`Sum()` takes a lambda that transforms a *single* element into a number:

```
.Sum(x => int.Parse(x))
```

Or, more simply,

```
.Sum(int.Parse)
```

This only works on the version 4 or later of the C# compiler (regardless of platform version)

Comment: first form works for me:) but second not really got error(cannot choose method from method group did you intend to invoke the method):(

Comment: I'm getting an error on the second form as well. Ambiguity between System.Func<string, int?> and System.Func<string, int>

Comment: @harry180: The second form requires C# 4+

Comment: @SLaks: What exactly changed in 4.0 to allow this? Why doesn't it work in previous versions?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/05/c-3-0-return-type-inference-does-not-work-on-member-groups.aspx

Comment: @SLaks: Great link, thanks. You can apply the second form in .NET Framework version 3.5 by creating the delegate explicitly `.Sum(new Func<string, int>(int.Parse))`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: Or `.Sum<string>(int.Parse)`

Comment: @SLaks: The missing part is the return type `int`. `string` can be inferred from `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: `Sum<>()` only takes one generic parameter.

Comment: @SLaks: Yes, but it does not work prior to 4.0 because it cannot infer the return type, so specifiing `<string>` which is the input type does not help. Tested with VS 2008.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
int number = myString.Split(',').Sum((x,y)=> y += int.Parse(x));
```

use

```
int number = myString.Split(',').Sum(x => int.Parse(x));
```

which will parse each element of `myString.Split(',')` to ints and add them.

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = "1,2,4,8,16".Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        .Select (str => int.Parse(str))
                        .Sum ( ) ;

Console.WriteLine( value ); // 31
```